# Input - Output Linking in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

How to pass the output of one test suite to another test suite in the robot framework?

Comment: Please be more specific: which info do you need and for which purpose? What have you tried?

Comment: Have you tried working with Global, Suite or Test Case scoped variables?

Comment: What do you mean with _output_? The overall test result of a suite like _PASS_ or _FAIL_ ?